# jquery not working in IE11

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

These are my methods for jQuery but it seems that it is not working in IE11, however the same code is working in firefox and chrome.

```
   function createCategory()
    {
    showLoading();

        $.post('<s:url value="/social/addEditCatSettings"/>',function(data){     
                hideLoading();
                $.prompt(data, {
                        title: "Add Categories",
                        buttons: { "Add": true, "Cancel": false },
                        submit: function(e,v,m,f){
                            if(v){
                                e.preventDefault();
                                saveUpdateCat();
                                }
                        }
                 });
            });
    }


  function saveUpdateCat(id)
    {
       var name = $('#catName').val();
       var name_sanitized = name.replace(some scritp....);
       if(name !== name_sanitized)
       {
            ShowMessage('Invalid input. Please try again.',true);
       }
       else
       {
       var type = false;

       jsonObj = [];
       item = {}
       item ["name"] = name;
       item ["type"] = type;


       if(typeof id != 'undefined')
        {
           item ["id"] = id;
        };


       if( btrim(name).length >0 )
        {
           item["mytoken"]='<s:property value="#session.mytoken"/>';

           $.post('<s:url value='/social/saveOrUpdateCatSettings' />',item,function(data){     

               if(data == 200)
                 {  
                     hideLoading(); 
                     $.fancybox.close();

                    if(typeof id != 'undefined')
                    {
                        ShowMessage('category updated successfully',false);
                    }
                    else
                     {
                        ShowMessage('category saved successfully',false);
                     }  
                     loadTabContent('MANAGECATS',profileId);
                 }
               else
                   {
                    ShowMessage('Please try again.',true);
                   }
             });




        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessage('Error,Please fill the required (*) fields',true);
            hideLoading();

        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Shouldn't this `saveUpdateCat();` be passing a variable to the function?

Comment: How does it "not work", and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: @Max please add any error messages and point to the code that is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hell of wasting hour,

i replaced $post by $ajax and modified lines accordingly, it worked for me.